# Jest testing: TypeError: (0 , _rtb.disableAllAds) is not a function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

A few questions on StackOverflow are like this one, but the suggestions haven't fixed my particular problem. I don't use react, only pure JS and I'm not able to continue my testing bc of this. Any help is appreciated.
I'm also still new to Jest testing.
This is the actual error I get (I get it on the first function so the 2nd will prob throw the error too)
What I don't get is it says it's not a function but it clearly is:

```
● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: (0 , _rtb.disableAllAds) is not a function

       99 |
      100 | // check for noads and dhb to disable RTB and ads
    > 101 | export const disableAds = disableAllAds(qsc);
          |                           ^
      102 | export const disableHb = disableAllHb(qsc);
```

A look into my files:
In my index file:

```
import {
  disableAllAds,
  disableAllHb,
} from "../src/rtb";

export const disableAds = disableAllAds(qsc);
export const disableHb = disableAllHb(qsc);
```

Then in rtb.js:

```
import {
  disableHb,
} from '../index';

export const disableAllAds = (qsc) => (qsc.noads === true || (typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.noads === 'true')) ? true : false;
export const disableAllHb = (qsc) => (qsc.dhb === true || (typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.disableHB === 'true')) ? true : false;
```

And my test file - tests/rtb.test.js:

```
import {
  disableAllAds, 
  disableAllHb, 
} from '../src/rtb';
```

I get this error even before I touch the test file if I have my Jest --watch on. 
I'm not sure why this is but I need help figuring this out so I can continue writing my tests.

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not make sure but that seems like 'circular dependency' issue to me.

Are you importing rtb from index and index from rtb?

Comment: I saw another comment on that in another post but i didn't understand what that meant. Are you IggyToad? In any case, It seems straightforward, I create a function in one place and export it to use somewhere else, and then export that value to use somewhere else, how would you suggest trying to investigate or solve this. Doesn't make sense to me how i can even have this error, thanks

Comment: That means 2 different files depending each other (importing from each other)

Comment: Ah I see your comment, and i am, but I'm taking disableAllAds, disableAllHb, in Index from rtb - And in rtb, i'm only taking disableHb but I see what you're saying now. What are some ways to fix this? Even when I create a helper.js in order to try to pass it around more (which i don't want to do) it still seems to throw a jest error ... Appreciate it

Comment: Thanks @yez, I am looking for solutions now online :D

Comment: 1) Focus on making the test pass as a first step. To make it pass copy those functions (yes duplicate them) directly to test file instead of importing. This will help you to make sure there is no any other problem. There were more than one problem in most challenging debugging sessions I have had in my life. --
2) If everything goes well,  replace all `disableHb` with `disableAllHb(qsc)` in index. --
3) remove the import statement from index. --
4) remove duplicated code --

Don't forget to check if test is passing after every step

Comment: Thanks for those suggestions, I've been researching for the last bit of time but this gives me a great place to start

Comment: update - definitely circular dependency but resolved now. I feel my code doesn't look as clean anymore though but i guess that will have to be for now